# Why SSH login works in shell but fails in all third parties via ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm using `ssh` to log in (prompt password first time) on a remote server.

In shell, using this command:

```
ssh root@myserver.com
```

works well! But all other db software applications that I tested (Dbeaver and Redis Desktop Manager) fail when I try to use SSH Tunnel. I selected my private key from */home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa*.

Example in Redis Desktop Manager:
[image: rdm]

Example in Dbeaver:
[image]

If I set the tunnel:

```
ssh root@myserver.com -L 6379:127.0.0.1:6379 -N
```

I can connect to 127.0.0.1:6379, i.e., the tunnel is working.
Why via third party is this not working?

In remote server is running CentOS 6 and in my desktop Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please explain "All other db softwares ... fail". How do they fail? What are they supposed to do that they don't do? Please be precise, and if necessary provide examples.

Comment: I tried to improve with examples of images that show when they fail.

Comment: Please confirm (in your question) that the very first `ssh root@myserver` logs you in _without_ prompting you for a password. (If it prompts for a password your public/private key is not set up correctly.)

Comment: After restarting my computer, when trying to login via ssh again, I was asked the password to unlock the id_dsa file.

Comment: There's your answer. Your other tools have no ability to unlock a private key, and no ability to talk to `ssh_agent` to have it authenticate on their behalf. You need to remove the password from the private certificate

Comment: roaima, I tried remove the password with command `ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa` then I restarted the computer and the password is no more prompted. But i can't login in third party yet. Do you have any tip?

Answer (score 1):

You said, in the comments,

> After restarting my computer, when trying to login via `ssh` again, I was asked the password to unlock the `id_dsa` file

There's at least part of the answer. Your other tools have no ability to unlock a private key, and no ability to talk to `ssh-agent` to have it authenticate on their behalf. You need to remove the password from the private certificate.

The syntax is:

```
ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```

And as you pointed out in your comment, the practical application of this is:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

---

The next part of the problem is that some third-party libraries for Java and .NET will only handle RSA ssh keys - and (in my experience) only up to a certainly key length. DSA and ECDSA are not options.

If you don't have `~/.ssh/id_rsa` then you are going to need to create it, and copy the public part to the remote host:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh remoteuser@remotehost 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

---

Another part of the problem may be that the private key is in the "wrong" format and [needs conversion](https://burnz.wordpress.com/2007/12/14/ssh-convert-openssh-to-ssh2-and-vise-versa/). From a brief perusal of the documentation for Redis Desktop Manager I don't believe this is the case but it would be worth double-checking. UPDATE: It appears that [JSCH - Invalid private key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15332517) confirms that the key is expected to be in OpenSSH format - which is what it appears you are already using.

Comment: id_dsa without password fail to auth via third party. I don't have id_rsa key then, new key generated using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and put in remotehost in authorized_keys files, but fail too. I dont know why we need to convert if we are using a new rsa key.

Comment: @Diogo, you installed `id_rsa.pub` into the `authorized_keys` files on the remote server. Have you changed Redis and DBeaver to use `id_rsa` instead of `id_dsa`?

Comment: Yes, i'm using id_rsa instead of dsa but Dbeaver and Redis _(2015-05-04 10:29:17 : Connection: SSH Connection error: Authentication Error)_ fail to login. I don't know more what can i do. At now i'm using custom tunnel set by shell.